# Simplify the following terms when $\lim_{x\to\infty }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I have the following terms

$A=\frac{a^2 (y + ay + 
   R x)^2 \Bigg(2 (1 + a) M y^2 x(y + ay + R x) S + (1 +
       a)^2 y^4 S^2 + M^2 x^2 \bigg(\left(y + ay + R x\right)^2 - R x^2 S\bigg)\Bigg)}{(1 +a)^2 R M x^3 S\Bigg(y (y + ay + R x)^2 S + M x(y + ay + R x- xS)^2\Bigg)}$

Can anyone help me to simplify A when $\lim_{x\to\infty }$. It needs some manipulation in order to make some terms divided by $x$ that can be ignored.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to _find_ $\lim_{x\to\infty} A(x,y,a,R,M,S)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both numerator and denominator are polynomials in $x$, so the limit as $x\to\infty$ depends only on the *highest-degree* terms on each side of the fraction bar. Here, if I'm counting correctly, the highest degree is 6 on both sides, leading to the terms
$$ \frac{a^2(Rx)^2M^2x^2((Rx)^2-Rx^2S) }
    {(1+a)^2RMx^3SMx(Rx-xS)^2 } =
\frac{ a^2R^3M^2(R-S) x^6 } {(1+a)^2RM^2S(R-S)^2  x^6 } $$
which is now easily simplified to
$$ \frac{a^2R^2}{(1+a)^2S(R-S)} $$
Things will go differently (and quite different terms will dominate) if $R=S$ ...

Comment: Great! Thank you very much dear. It works perfectly.

Comment: @userUK: As you can see from the final limit above, when $R$ is near $S$, the limit depends _crtitically_ on the sign and magnitude of $R-S$. You cannot make that dependency go away by (valid) algebraic rewritings.